# DIY fixed voltage solenoid inductor -- do more loops actually make the B field stronger?

Tags: resistance, electromagnetism, solenoid, magnetics, diy

I'm building a custom electromagnet. Given the fixed voltage, I'm wondering if there's actually a benefit to putting more wire loop layers in my solenoid given the trade-off of increased resistance/ decreased current. This is basically an issue I'm seeing from combining Ohm's law with the equation for the B-field of a solenoid.

My solenoid is of height H; it's composed of M layers of wire loops, where each individual layer has N = (solenoid height)/(diameter of current wire) current loops stacked on top of each other; Then, since the B field is interior to the solenoid , and letting MN=[#]:

$$B= \mu_0 \frac{MN}{H}\cdot I =\mu_0 \frac{[\#]}{H}\cdot I$$

Now my voltage difference is being supplied by a fixed 9 V battery. From Ohm's law, my currents are clearly I=V/R, but my resistance increases with my wire layers. If R<sub>i</sub>  is the radius of the i'th layer, then the length of a single loop in the i'th layer is \$ L_i =2\pi R_i \$.
And since there are N loops per layer, the total resistance is:
$$ R=\frac{r\rho}{A} L_{tot}= \frac{\rho}{A} \cdot \sum N\cdot L_i = 
\frac{\rho}{A} \cdot MN\cdot 2\pi \cdot \sum R_i /M \propto MN\cdot <R> $$

So then the the total resistance is just [#]*(average radius), and this combined with the fixed voltage gives:
$$ I\propto \frac{1}{[\#]<R>}$$

Then plugging this current into the B-field equation gives that:

$$B\propto \frac{[\#]}{H}\cdot \frac{1}{[\#]<R>}=\frac{1}{H<R>} $$

So this tells me that with my fixed voltage, the only thing really changing my B field strength is the average radius of a loop layer, since the B field strength added by more layers gets canceled out by the decrease in current strength from resistance. But more loop layers just increases the average radius, so that makes me think I'm just making my magnet weaker by spinning extra layers onto it.

Anyway, I'd appreciate it if anyone could confirm if my reasoning is right with this issue. Additionally, if my thinking is right, is there any good way to work around it besides increasing my battery strength?

Comment: Yes certainly more turns  also more current both incr. L mH and B field. And I is limited by battery and wire resistance, so what gauge of wire is allowed thus what is the limit of copper volume outside and core volume inside means  more dimensions are needed such as the travel of the core in the solenoid, to determine the optimal wire length uH/m and ohms/m.  B & L will reduce with height, so the volume of wire outside and core inside matters with core travel and mutual coupling of flux. Then there is BEMF reduction if the core is moving fast.  A solver eqn could be made for fixed l or d or R

Comment: You want to maximize current but can you increase winding diameter and wire guage to any value to keep resistance constant? Or will you have volume, cost constraints

Answer (score 1):

### The Coil

We're only concerned with ampere-turns, because all the geometry is held constant.  Note this assumes a given (hollow cylindrical) winding volume, with 100% fill factor (no gaps between turns, so it doesn't matter whether it's a solid slug or millions of turns).  And a tangential current flow, and that we're not worried about, like, temp rise or anything.

Consider the case going from N = 1 to N = 2, where N is the total number of turns.  Instead of a cylindrical shell, we have two shells stacked (or nested, or anything that gives a 50% cross section to each turn).  This halves the cross-section per turn, doubling the resistance per turn.  The turns are doubled, so total resistance is quadrupled.  At the same applied voltage, current is quartered.  Since turns are doubled, ampere-turns is halved overall.

### The Battery

There are no ideal sources.  If there were, you'd simply maximize field by setting N = 1.  Well, maybe still not, given how much power dissipation and temp rise might ensue (we have assumed resistive conductors here!).

Anyway, for something like a 9 V (PP3 type) battery, we are limited to a few 100 mA of load, and at that, for maybe an hour, tops.  Therefore, we need to target that resistance: i.e., (9 V) / (100 mA) = 90 Ω or so.

This will determine the number of turns, and the resulting field strength.

It appears you left \$A\$ out of your calculations: it depends on \$N\$ and \$M\$.  This will correct the discrepancy I think.  You can apply this (above, and yours) reasoning to determine what wire size to choose for a given resistance and dimensions.  Note that wire is not available in any size, but comes in standard tabulated sizes, so use the calculation as a starting point, and try designing with a few neighboring gauges to find the closest. Protip: round wire fill factor is typically around 70%, so underestimate turns by about as much.

### Related

If you need a particular magnetization / flux density, consider adding pole pieces.  This reduces the enclosed volume, while greatly increasing the efficiency of the electromagnet.  If you need a certain volume *and* intensity, you will need at least some amount of power -- which might not be available from such a small battery (again, assuming PP3 for example).  In that case, reconsider your underlying problems (how much field/volume is really needed, can a bigger battery be fitted, can permanent magnets be used to help, can the problem be solved in other ways..).

Comment: +1 for Pole Pieces (didn't know it had a name). The geometry is a very important factor. You want a ferromagnetic path in roughly a horseshoe path. And you want whatever you are trying to pick-up to complete the path.